# Avoiding a customized Copy Directory function to go on infinite loop when copying folder into himself

Tags: c#, foreach, directory, .net, file-copying

I'm trying this function, which copies all files from a folder, and relative subfolders with files to another location:

```
using System.IO;

 private static bool CopyDirectory(string SourcePath, string DestinationPath, bool overwriteexisting)
        {
            bool ret = true;
            try
            {
                SourcePath = SourcePath.EndsWith(@"\") ? SourcePath : SourcePath + @"\";
                DestinationPath = DestinationPath.EndsWith(@"\") ? DestinationPath : DestinationPath + @"\";

                if (Directory.Exists(SourcePath))
                {
                    if (Directory.Exists(DestinationPath) == false)
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(DestinationPath);

                    foreach (string fls in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath))
                    {
                        FileInfo flinfo = new FileInfo(fls);
                        flinfo.CopyTo(DestinationPath + flinfo.Name, overwriteexisting);
                    }

                    foreach (string drs in Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath))
                    {
                        DirectoryInfo drinfo = new DirectoryInfo(drs);
                        if (CopyDirectory(drs, DestinationPath + drinfo.Name, overwriteexisting) == false || drs.Substring(drs.Length-8) == "archive")
                            ret = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ret = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", e.Message, Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine, e.StackTrace);
                ret = false;
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

It works good until you have to copy the folder into another location, but when you have to create a folder  in itself (In my example I'm doing a subfolder called "archive" to keep track of the last folder files changes) it goes in infinite loops, because it keeps rescanning itself in the Directory.GetDirectories foreach loop, finding the newly created subfolders and going on nesting the same subfolder over and over until it reaches a "Path name too long max 260 charachters limit exception".

I tried to avoid it by using the condition

> || drs.Substring(drs.Length-8) == "archive")

which should check the directory name, but it doesn't seem to work.

I thought than, different solutions like putting a max subfolders depth scan (I.E max 2 subfolders) so it doesn't keep rescanning all the nested folders, but I can't find such property in Directory object.

I cannot copy the whole thing to a temp folder and then into the real folder because the next time I will scan it, it will rescan archive folder too.

I tought about putting all the directory listing in an ArrayList of Directory objects or so so maybe I can check something like DirName or so but I don't know if such property exists.

Any solution?

Comment: Already tried before substring, no luck. Even comparing the exact string value taken from the debugger lead to no result.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where recursion doesn't really work, as the list of directories and files always changes as you copy. A better solution is to get the list of all files and folders in advance.

You can get all files and directories in a tree using the [Directory.GetFiles(String,String,SearchOption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) and [Directory.GetDirectories(String,String,SearchOption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314.aspx) with SearchOption set to [SearchOption.AllDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448.aspx). These will return all files and all directories respectively.

You can follow these steps to copy the files:

1. Get the list of all source directories and sort them in ascending order. This will ensure that parent directories appear before their child directories.
2. Create the target directory structure by creating the child directories in their sorted order. You won't get any path conflicts as the sort order ensures you always create the parent folders before the child folders
3. Copy all the source files to the target directories as before. Order doesn't really matter at this point as the target directory structure already exists.

A quick example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sourcePath = @"c:\MyRoot\TestFolder\";

        var targetPath = @"c:\MyRoot\TestFolder\Archive\";

        var directories=Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        if(!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);

        foreach (var directory in directories)
        {
            var relativePath = GetRelativePath(sourcePath, directory);
            var toPath = Path.Combine(targetPath, relativePath);
            if (!Directory.Exists(toPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(toPath);
            }
        }

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var relativePath = GetRelativePath(sourcePath, file);
            var toPath = Path.Combine(targetPath, relativePath);
            if (!File.Exists(toPath))
                File.Copy(file,toPath);
        }
    }

    //This is a very quick and dirty way to get the relative path, only for demo purposes etc
    private static string GetRelativePath(string rootPath, string fullPath)
    {
        return Path.GetFullPath(fullPath).Substring(rootPath.Length);
    }
```